# Нужно вывести на экран последовательность # и ' '

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Нужно вывести вот такую фигуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я это решил на python вот так:

```
for x in range(6):
for y in range(x+1):
    if x == 0:
        z = ''
    elif x == 1:
        z = ' '
    elif x == 2:
        z = '  '
    elif x == 3:
        z = '   '
    elif x == 4:
        z = '    '
    elif x == 5:
        z = '     '
    elif x == 6:
        z = '      '
print('#', z, '#', sep='')
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, менее громоздкое решение

Comment: Кст, подправьте код в вопросе, восстановив правильные отступы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
for x in range(6):
    z = ' ' * x
    print('#' + z + '#')
```

Результат:

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```